# Stripe checkout works locally, but failing to pass 'card' when deployed to heroku

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, railsapps

My Rails 4.0 app is able to charge a payment successfully when running on localhost, but the same app deployed to Heroku fails.  My Stripe logs say that the 'card' field is empty.  I feel that the code is legit, but that something is failing between Bootstrap, Heroku, and Stripe.  I have been sure to precompile assets before pushing to Heroku.  Any ideas?

Comment: Let me check your Code and get right back to you !

Comment: Try adding some log statements to your JavaScript code (logging to the JavaScript console) to debug.